# C# - Need ideas on executing SQL and exporting to excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, export-to-excel

Right now my code exports all the columns that it does the query for into an excel file. The SQL commands that are executed are in stored procedures.
I want to have the option to be able to specify which columns from the SQL data I want to export.

One method that I am thinking of would be to have the user be able to pick what they want and concatenate them into a SQL query instead of using the commands in the stored procedure.

I also tried to put parameters into the stored procedures inside of the select area thinking that it would be simple to have parameters in the select field but from what I understand so far is that it's not allowed due to the possibility of SQL injections.

I've seen some examples of people using DataSets and DataTables to hold the SQL data but then export all of it to excel. But if you use it that way wouldn't you need a bunch of conditional statements to check before writing out that column?

Are there any other methods? Code posted below just to show what I am doing so far.

```
private SqlDataSource GetDataSource(string FruitType)
{

    SqlDataSource tempDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
    tempDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ServerConnectionString"].ToString();
    tempDataSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    switch (ReportType)
    {
        case "Oranges":
            tempDataSource.SelectCommand = "getOrange";                                          
            break;
        case "Apples":
            tempDataSource.SelectCommand = "getApples";                
            break;
        case "Pineapples":
            tempDataSource.SelectCommand = "getPineapples";
            break;
        case "Watermelons":                
            tempDataSource.SelectCommand = "getWatermelons";                
            break;
        case "GrapeFruit":                
            tempDataSource.SelectCommand = "getGrapeFruit";                
            break;
    }

    tempDataSource.DataBind();
    return tempDataSource;
}
protected void btnSaveData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=";
    attachment += "Fruit Data";
    attachment += ".xls";

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    GridView gvTemp = new GridView();
    gvTemp.Attributes["runat"] = "server";

    SqlDataSource ds = GetDataSource(FruitType);
    gvTemp.DataSource = ds;
    gvTemp.DataBind();
    gvTemp.RenderControl(htw);
    Page.Controls.Add(gvTemp);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use temp tables to specify which columns do you want to get from stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetDiffDataExample
      @columnsStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) -- Needed columns
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @columnsStatement + N' INTO ##TempTable FROM dbo.TestTable'
    EXEC sp_executeSql @query
    SELECT * FROM ##TempTable
    DROP TABLE ##TempTable
END
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Few questions but when I put my variables in the columns parameter do they need to be in the sql format already? Such as 'col name1, col name2'
Also, why do you have to insert it into another table after selecting the columns from the table just to select all from the test table? Isn't it kind of redundant?

Comment: Yes, columns parameter have to be in the sql format. This is just example, so you can write your own parameters and select data in the same way. As far as I know there is only one option to get different columns result from procedure without manual coding. If you want to let your user select desirable colums it suppose to be simpliest example.